# Can google steal my Bitcoins if I store the private key in Google Keep note

Tags: security

A while ago I put all my addresses with private keys (although they did not have that much money in them) onto a google keep note. I put it on a password protected notepad on my phone now, but could anyone have stolen them from my google keep note?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'd be a huge violation of user trust if a Google employee looked at customer data and did something like that, so I'd say extremely unlikely.

That said, you shouldn't ever put your private keys on the internet.

Lastly, if this did happen and it involved any substantial amount of money, Google would be able to determine which employee accessed your data, which you could then very likely use in civil court to recover your stolen BTC.

Disclaimer: I work at Google.

Comment: So there can't be a middle man in between me and the server where the note was stored? Also how long does it take from when the time the clicked delete on that note and when it is actually deleted for real?

Comment: There cannot be middleman, because all Google connections are HTTPS encrypted nowadays. If you want to be sure you can always move coins to a different address, though. That is more safe than deleting the note, as you have 100% control over the operation.

Comment: The same argument goes for storing your money at a bank.

Comment: I agree with @MikkoOhtamaa about the man-in-the-middle attack. SSL should solve that problem for you.

Google also (now) encrypts even more due to that whole Prism thing: https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2013/10/prism-is-not-enough

Comment: @RileyPotts: I don't think it's safe to say "how long it takes" for something to be *fully* deleted, as that's actually a really complicated question.

The general gist here is: it's a bad idea to put your private key anywhere on the internet (Google or not). If you did this already, just move your coins to a new address, and the problem goes away. If you want a safe back-up, consider a BIP38 encrypted paper wallet in a safety deposit box (https://bitcoinpaperwallet.com/bip38-password-encrypted-wallets/)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that someone at Google may use that information to steal your bitcoins, but it is *extremely* unlikely.